# How to change drupal commerce credit card default value

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, credit-card, commerce

I have a drupal commerce install, the credit card on the payment pane has this has default values for the expiration month and expiration date. 
I have tried to change the default values to 'mm' and 'yy' but it won't work.

```
$form['commerce_payment']['payment_details']['credit_card']['exp_month']['#default_value']= 'mm';

$form['commerce_payment']['payment_details']['credit_card']['exp_year']['#default_value']= 'yy';
```

When I run

```
dpm($form['commerce_payment']['payment_details']['credit_card']['exp_year']['#default_value'])
```

it displays 'yy' but the form won't pick up the change. I can change everything else but those 2 default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass an explicit numeric values to this parameter, not the date format strings.

Look at the line #119 for the proper implementation [here](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!payment!includes!commerce_payment.credit_card.inc/DC) (click "View source" under the functions list table.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me there but I want to pass 'mm' and 'yy' as respective default values of the exp_month and exp_year.

Comment: as it is a select element you have to have 'MM' in an options list first. `$form['commerce_payment']['payment_details']['credit_card']['exp_month'][#options]['mm'] = 'MM';`

Comment: The above solution will make your default "MM" value available for users to select. It's not the best possible way. Maybe you need smth like [Compact forms module](https://www.drupal.org/project/compact_forms) or just a bit of js magic?